# Trying to understand gas costs: Why does this simple function cost so much?

Tags: gas

I have this code for calculating the `sqrt(x)`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract myContract {
    function sqrt(uint x) external pure returns (uint y) {
        uint z = (x + 1) / 2;
        y = x;
        while (z < y) {
            y = z;
            z = (x / z + z) / 2;
        }
    }
}
```

If I have a look at the yellow paper (https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) each of the operations in the `while` loop cost 3 or 5 gas (`W_verylow` and `W_low` sets of operations). I would expect definitely less than 15 gas per loop. However I have done a couple of tests with these results:

A:

```
Number of loops = 60
Total gas cost = 29750
Gas per loop = 495
```

B:

```
Number of loops = 97
Total gas cost = 34850
Gas per loop = 360
```

Granted that there are some fixed costs, but we can also check the cost per look looking only at the difference in number of loops:

`(34850-29750)/(97-60) = 137 gas per loop`

Still way higher than what I was expecting. What am I misunderstanding here?

Thanks

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled?

Comment: No, first time I heard about this, I will have a look and come back with some comment, thanks for the tip!

Comment: I'd suggest to execute the function in a debugger step by step without optimization. Remix for example show how much gas is used in every step.